# Calculating distance between pixel values on raster layers using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, proximity

I am attempting to perform a proximity analysis to determine the distance pixel values on different rasters layers.  For example, one layer is roads (with all roads having a value of 1) and one is oil wells (with all wells having a value of 1).  I would eventually like to overlay all of the results to see which activities are in closest proximity, how close they are, and which general area within my analysis experiences the most pressure.  What is the best way to go about this?  Should I perform proximity analyses for each separate layer and then use the raster calculator to combine them?

I am using QGIS and am not too sure how to identify the "target pixel" within the GDAL proximity tool.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

In the tool there is a field called 'values'. You can enter the target value (i.e 1) here.

You could treat them separately and combine later of combine first and then do the proximity. The values field should be able to take a list of values so you can assign your road and oil wells different values using the raster calculator

Alternatively, you could use the command line. gdal_proximity.py is the same as the tool in Qgis